# FileResult Controllers that will also Redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this `public FileResult` method that if it finds the file I want to return it. If the file is missing I want to Redirect the users to the login page. Is there a way to do this?

```
Error is can't convert Redirect to file results

 [HttpGet]
        public FileResult GetFile(string fileManagerGuidId,string accessGroup)
        var FileInfo = GetFile(fileManagerGuidId);
        if (FileInfo != null)
        {
            FileManagerLog _filemanagerLog = new FileManagerLog();
            _filemanagerLog.CustomerId =Request.Cookies["customerid"] != null ? 
            Convert.ToInt32(Request.Cookies["customerid"].Value) : 0;
            _filemanagerLog.FileManagerGuid = new Guid(fileManagerGuidId);
            SaveFileManagerLog(_filemanagerLog);
            byte[] fileBytes = FileInfo.FileData;
            return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, 
            FileInfo.FileName);
         }
         else
         {
             return Redirect("~/Login");
         }
        }
```

Comment: In what way does the code shown fail?  As a guess, it looks like you just need to have the method return type be `ActionResult`.

Comment: that is correct I am getting an convert error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method is defined to explicitly return a `FileResult`:

```
public FileResult GetFile(string fileManagerGuidId,string accessGroup)
```

Since you also want to potentially return other results, the return type needs to be more generic, something from which the different result types inherit:

```
public ActionResult GetFile(string fileManagerGuidId,string accessGroup)
```